# Folder to put files in meteor that won't be used by the client or server?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, meteor

I'm trying to include bootstrap less files so I can easily override them with a custom theme but the individual less files will be served to the client. I want to be able to put just a single less file outside of that and import from there. That way only the compiled less file will be served up.

Are there any folders that I can use that meteor won't bundle up for the client or the server?

Something like

```
/meteor-project
  /external
    /bootstrap-overrides
      variables.less
    /bootstrap
      /less
        reset.less
        etc..
  mybootstraptheme.less
```

where mybootstaptheme.less imports from external/bootstrap like this:

```
// CSS Reset
@import "external/bootstrap/less/reset.less";

// Core variables and mixins
@import "external/bootstrap-overrides/variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "external/bootstrap/less/mixins.less";

// Grid system and page structure
@import "external/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less";
//etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files placed in the `tests` folder will be ignored.

```
/meteor-project
  /tests
```

Although using that folder for LESS files is not ideal. Ideally the LESS compiler would ignore files that start with `_` allowing for imports, but there is an open issue concerning this.

[`less` @imports fail](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/203)

Comment: switched to devel branch because of error discussed in linked and put less files in test and everything worked as expected. It would be nice if we could get a folder that was excluded like tests is.